# One Thread Waiting on Method of Another

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I have one thread(A) that kicks off another (B). Thread A must wait for thread B's initialisation method to complete before it continues on.

I am currently using thread B as a lock like so:

```
synchronized (B) {

            try {

                B.start();

                while (!B.getIsInitialized()) {
                    B.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.logStackTrace(this + " run: Exception detected", e);
            }
        }
```

At the very beginning of B's run method, I have the following:

```
synchronized(this) {

        initialize();

        notify();
    }
```

This all seems to work, but I can;t find anything online about using one of the two threads as the lock. Is what I'm doing correct? I should also note that thread B does not terminate once initialisation is complete, and needs to continue on so I can't simply use .join().

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Don't `synchronized` or `wait` or `notify` on `Thread` instances.

Comment: That seems to be consistent with the lack of locking on Thread instances I've found online. Should I be using some sort of public static object in thread A? I don't know that I can pass any objects over as a parameter..

Comment: One thing which can break this code -- call `notifyAll()` instead of `notify`. The rest of kind of kinky, but should work.

Comment: So in your opinion this code is fine, but I need to be calling notifyAll instead? There will only be a single thread (A) waiting on thread B.

Comment: See the javadoc of [`Thread#join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29). `notify` and `wait` are used internally on `Thread` instances. You'll have undesired effects. Use some other shared object or some of the `java.util.concurrent` synchronization primitives.

Comment: Ah I do see that now in the Javadoc. In this scenario, would a public static Object in thread A to lock upon be the solution? Or, if I decide to use some other object from the concurrency collection, is making that object public and static in thread A be best practice if I am unable to pass the lock as a parameter?

Comment: You can use a `CountDownLatch` with initial value of 1. Thread A calls `await()` to wait for initialization; thread B calls `countDown()` as soon as initialization is done.

Comment: Thanks @isnot2bad. I went with your suggestion and after some research on it, the CountDownLatch is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work definitely,for what you want to achieve. The only think I will mention is that try to use synchronized as less as you can because synchronization is 'expensive'. So if some part of code is not need to be in synchronized part then don't.  This part of code will do the same but synchronization is done only in thread B.

```
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {       
     new ThreadA().start();
  }
}


class ThreadA extends Thread{       
    private void startThreadB(){
        ThreadB tb=new ThreadB();
        tb.start();                 
        // to some code if you need;
        tb.isInit();
    }

    public void run(){
            System.out.println("Thread A is started ");
            startThreadB(); 
            while(true){
                // your code for execution of thread A
                System.out.println("thread A is working");
                try{ Thread.sleep(2000);} catch(Exception e){}
            }
    }       
}



  class ThreadB extends Thread{
     private boolean init;               
     public ThreadB(){   init=false;     }
     private void init(){
         // some code here for init
         synchronized(this){
               init= true;
               notifyAll();
               System.out.println("Thread B has been inicialized !");
         }
     }


     public void isInit(){
         synchronized(this){
             while(!init) { try{ wait();}catch(InterruptedException e){}}
         }
     }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Thread B is started");
        init();
        while(true){
            // your code for execution of thread B
            System.out.println("Thread B is working");
            try{ Thread.sleep(2000);} catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}
```